# Why is the datatype of a column `<I<dbl>> and not just `<dbl>` after applying the identity function?

Tags: r, types

I have a case where I need to apply a dynamically selected function onto a column of a tibble. In some cases, I don't want the values to change at all -- then I select the identity function `I()`.

After applying `I()` the datatype of the column changes from `<dbl>` to `<I<dbl>>`. Why is that? Why is it not just double again?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = (1:3*pi))
print(df)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#       x
#   <dbl>
# 1  3.14
# 2  6.28
# 3  9.42
df %<>% mutate(x = I(x))
print(df)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#          x
#   <I<dbl>>`         <-- Why <I...> and not <dbl>?
# 1     3.14
# 2     6.28
# 3     9.42
```

How can I just get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I()` is not the identity function, technically (that would be `identity`). `I()` is to inhibit interpretation/conversion, saying that the component should be used "as is". Further `I(...)` returns an object of class `"AsIs"`, which is and should be recognized as something unique from its non-`I(...)` counterpart. As for the effect of this class ... I don't know of any (though I don't use them regularly, so I might be missing something).

And you can still operate on this, it's just classes differently.

```r
dput(1:3)
# 1:3
dput(I(1:3))
# structure(1:3, class = "AsIs")

tibble(x = (1:3*pi)) %>%
  mutate(x = I(x)) %>%
  mutate(y = x + 1)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#          x        y
#   <I<dbl>> <I<dbl>>
# 1     3.14     4.14
# 2     6.28     7.28
# 3     9.42    10.4
```

though that new column is also `"AsIs"`.